# Which latest version of ubuntu is suitable for my old system?

Tags: installation

My system specifications are:

1. Intel Celeron x86 Family 6 Model 13 Stepping 8 GenuineIntel 1.5 Ghz
2. 224 MB of RAM
3. 30 GB Hard Disk
4. Graphics VGA 64 MB 1024x768

Answer (score 4):

I think you might like to try Lubuntu, which is intended for lower-powered computers like yours. See this question: [How much faster is Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68067/how-much-faster-is-lubuntu)

Comment: you can try to download the alternate lubuntu instalation for your old machine: http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso

Answer (score 0):

I would just use standard 11.10 32-bit just in case though I am a little worried about the amount of RAM you stated. The hard-disk space is definitively enough. The processor should also work. But for a decent speed i would use another Linux distro for use on an older less powerful machine.

Comment: Thank You Sean. It would be really helpful of u, if u can name some linux distro for my system.